# grunt-jsxhint and jsxhint not acting the same

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, react-native, grunt-jsxhint, jsxhint

When I use `npm install -g jsxhint` I am able to use it to lint my jsx code, like so:

[image]

But when I try to use `grunt-jsxhint` to setup a lint command, it fails:

[image]

My Gruntfile is super simple:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsxhint');

  /* Project configuration */
  grunt.initConfig({
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      ignores: [],
      additionalSuffixes: ['.js', '.ios.js']
    },
    jshint: {
      all: ['./app/index.ios.js']
    }
  });

  /* Test Tasks */
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint']);
};
```

Why are these outputting different results?

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsxhint
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsxhint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsxHint and JSHint arent the best tools for linting JSX. JSHint does not support JSX and all JsxHint does is transforms JSX and then runs JSHint on the transformed code. 
I have been using (and would highly recommend) [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) with the [React plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react). This is better since Eslint can parse any Javascript flavor using custom parsers (like [esprima-fb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-fb))

Sample `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
    "parser": "esprima-fb",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },

    "rules": {
        "no-mixed-requires": [0, false],
        "quotes": [2, "single"],
        "strict": [1, "never"],
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "curly": 1,
        "no-bitwise": 1,
        "max-len": [1, 110, 4],
        "vars-on-top": 0,
        "guard-for-in": 1,
        "react/display-name": 1,
        "react/jsx-quotes": [2, "double", "avoid-escape"],
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
        "react/prop-types": 2,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/wrap-multilines": 2
    },

    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },

    "plugins": [ "react" ],

    "globals": {
        "d3": true,
        "require": "true",
        "module": "true",
        "$": "true",
        "d3": "true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong with my Gruntfile.

You need to load the task in: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsxhint');`

After `grunt.initConfig({})` has been set.

This would look like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  /* Project configuration */
  grunt.initConfig({
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      ignores: [],
      additionalSuffixes: ['.js', '.ios.js']
    },
    jshint: {
      all: ['./app/index.ios.js']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsxhint');

  /* Test Tasks */
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint']);
};
```